# Chat room refresh in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, refresh, chatroom

I'm working on a chatroom type thing where users type in text and hit enter and it gets posted to the main page. I built it with PHP. I have a working model, however to see new posts you have to click the refresh button in the browser. Is there a way to auto refresh this in JavaScript? I'm sure there is, but it seems like if it were to refresh every two seconds than it would be very slow and resource intensive. So is there a work-around? If not well than I guess we could just go with the refresh every few seconds.

I'm now an advanced JavaScript user, so please comment your code and explain what I need to change. Thanks a million!!

Oh, PS, All the comments are saved in a MySQL database and are auto-generated through PHP.

Comment: Use Ajax. Automated full-page refreshes would discard what your users were typing.

Comment: Auto refresh is a terrible idea. Ajax is the way to go.

Comment: Don't use only Ajax, use some push technology(-ies): WebSockets, ServerSentEvents, long polling ...

Comment: Okay, I know nothing about ajax, but I'm willing to learn. What do I need to do?

Comment: @kylemorgan49: I recommend looking into [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). They will allow you to make realtime applications using WebSockets and such (as Bergi mentioned)

Comment: @kylemorgan49: No problem. Googling "nodejs socket.io chat" will also bring up several results that should help you. Good luck!

Comment: @kylemorgan49: OK, if you don't know about Ajax, you should first learn about that before getting into server-push.

Comment: Did you mean to say "I'm *not* an advanced Javascript user?" Just checking because your following comments seem to indicate that.

Comment: `@ Bergi` That's why I didn't suggest Websockets. @MichaelMior weird, I was pretty sure that I've read *not* the first time. Didn't notice the actual wording in the question until you mentioned it.

Comment: @MichaelMior Yeah, sorry, I DONT know much JavaScript.

Comment: I have to have this app ready by tomorrow morning :(. I don't have time to learn a whole new language right now. Could someone link me to a good simple tutorial? Ideally a video? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do a window refresh every X seconds but as you mentioned there is no need to reload the full page in this scenario.  As you said that all the new text comments are in sql, what you can do is using AJAX to call a php function to update them live on screen without a page reload at all.

```
setTimeout("updateChatAJAx()",2000);
```

This javascript line will call the "updatechatAJAx" javascript function every 2 seconds.

```
    //Load the message View
    function updateChatAJAx(){
        var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                        //The response
                        document.getElementById('MoreID').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                }
        }
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "getMessages.php", true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

This above function will be the ajax function which will call the get the output pf your getMessages.php and put the messages into the "MoreID" div element

Comment: Never ever pass strings to `setTimeout`

Comment: Set the update function to work with 5 seconds span. 2 seconds is way too little time.

Comment: This might work, but for what I'm using it for, it needs to refresh like every two seconds - which IS too much, but I need it. I'm looking into things like meteor.com right now and i'm on the phone with go daddy. Well see what happens!